# Django bound form is invalid - how to get default validation work?

Tags: python, django

I m new to django, I m writing a class-based view for a form.
The problem is, this form renders well, but when posting I get form invalid.

I am not sure what should I do to get default validators validate the form. There are two fields in the form. One is choice field, whose choices are set dynamically based on logged-in user. Another is CharField. There is no need of validation as CharField is free text and ChoiceField is based on user's data.

forms.py

```
class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    phones= forms.ChoiceField(label='Select phone', choices = (), required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=True)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print >> sys.stderr, 'form init'

        self.fields['phones'].choices = [(ids.id, ids.phone_model.short_name) for ids in GCM_RegId.objects.filter(user=user)]

    def process(self, user):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        regid_id = cd['phones'].value
        gcm_regid = GCM_RegId.objects.filter(id=regid_id)
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(FormView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    form_class = HomeForm
    success_url = 'home'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        if(form.is_bound):
            print >> sys.stderr, "Form is Bound"
        else:
            print >> sys.stderr, "Form is NOT Bound"

        if form.is_valid():
            print >> sys.stderr, "Form Valid"
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            print >> sys.stderr, "Form NOT Valid"
            return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)       

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = HomeForm(self.request.user, {})
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.process(self.request.user)
        print >> sys.stderr, "RegIdSubmitView form_valid"
        return super(HomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: You're overthinking things. Specifically, you've misinterpreted Django's view design and broke several features of the `FormMixin`. I suggest you take a look at the source for [generic edit views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py). There's no need to override the HTTP method handlers (`ProcessFormView`) unless your interpretation of form processing requires something else--focus on overriding methods of `FormMixin` to add custom functionality, but make sure to do it judicially to not omit out any base functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is when you create the form instance, you forget to pass the request.POST data to your form class, the get_form method should be:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    form = HomeForm(self.request.user, data=self.request.POST)
    return form
```

Or, I think the better way for get_form is:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    return form_class(self.request.user, **self.get_form_kwargs()
```

Check the the source code of get_form_kwargs method in django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin, it automatically handle the request's PUT/POST data and files for you.